# Interop.PowerPoint: How set slide background from another slide?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-office, powerpoint, office-interop

*Sorry my English :)*

I need to set the background color second slide from fifth slide

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var presentationPath = @"d:\myPresentation.pptx";
    var app = new PowerPoint.Application();
    var presentation = app.Presentations.Open(presentationPath, WithWindow: MsoTriState.msoFalse);
    var slide2 = presentation.Slides[2];
    var slide5 = presentation.Slides[5];

    slide2.FollowMasterBackground = MsoTriState.msoFalse;
    var backgroundStyle = slide5.BackgroundStyle;
    try
    {
        slide2.BackgroundStyle = backgroundStyle;
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($@"Slide5.BackgroundStyle: {backgroundStyle.ToString()}");
        Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    finally
    {
        presentation.Close();
    }                      
}
```

but code throw exception (second line):

> Slide5.BackgroundStyle: msoBackgroundStyleNotAPreset
>
> Slide (unknown member) : Integer out of range. 0 is not in the valid
>   range of 1 to 12.

Comment: If you set FollowMasterBackground to false then the background style is automatically set to 0 (msoBackgroundStyleNotAPreset) . You cannot explicitly set it to 0.

Comment: @ShyamPillai, I set `FollowMasterBackground` to false only for `slide2` or this settings also automatically set 0 for `slide5.BackgroundStyle`?

Comment: This line slide2.FollowMasterBackground = MsoTriState.msoFalse; will automatically change the background style to 0. Have you checked if slide5 has any backgroundstyle set? It may be possible that it’s FollowMasterBackground is already false.

Comment: @ShyamPillai, on the view fifth slide (slide5) has yellow background.

Comment: Yellow background is not necessarily the same as a backgroundstyle. What is the backgroundstyle value, it may be 0

Comment: @ShyamPillai, `Slide5.BackgroundStyle = msoBackgroundStyleNotAPreset (0)`, I also showed that in my question above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167485/discussion-between-adamshakhabov-and-shyam-pillai).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved problem

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var presentationPath = @"d:\myPresentation.pptx";
        var app = new PowerPoint.Application();
        var presentation = app.Presentations.Open(presentationPath, WithWindow: MsoTriState.msoFalse);
        var slide2 = presentation.Slides[2];
        var slide5 = presentation.Slides[5];

        slide2.FollowMasterBackground = MsoTriState.msoFalse;
        slide2.Background.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = slide5.Background.Fill.ForeColor.RGB;                      
    }
```